# useState doesn't work first time when given date in string while implementing stop watch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state, stopwatch

I have uploaded my code here in https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-lehmann-o4thw?file=/src/Layout.tsx

I am trying to do a stopwatch. But working not as expected due to hook issue.

```
 const startTimer = async () => {
   setDisableStart(true);
   setDisableStop(false);
   const rightNowTime = await Date.now().toString();
   setCurrentTime(rightNowTime);
   interval = setInterval(() => {
     calculateTime();
   }, 1);
};
```

I can see problem with setCurrentTime(rightNowTime) is not updating current time

Please, somebody, suggest

Comment: Can you update your question to include ***in the question*** a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code you've an issue with? Please also include better details about the issue. What is the hook issue?

Comment: I have added my code in above link. @DrewReese updated

Comment: Which `useState` isn't working? There are 8 `useState` hooks in `App` alone. What is the issue? What are you expecting? What debugging have you done already?

Comment: setCurrentTime(rightNowTime) is not working first time. When I reset or stop the button then If I start, startButton then it will work.

Comment: Seems to update just fine in your sandbox. I click start and see `currentTime` update from `"00"` to `"16415......"` timestamp. Is this not what you are expecting? Seems you may be referring to the "minutes" display of your UI. Actually, it seems all the UI (minutes, seconds, ms) have issue after pausing.

Comment: When you click start, min and sec starts from some random number. This is beacuase, const milliseconds =  totalTime + timeNow - Number(currentTime). Where currentTime getting 0 always eventhough im setting when i click start button

Comment: It's not random, it's the current dateTime `rightNowTime`. What do you want to happen when start is clicked? What should the UI be? I may be easier to update only a single time delta state and compute the minutes, seconds, and milliseconds when rendering.

Comment: If you put console.log at line number 26 after setCurrentTime(rightNowTime); and click on start button you will get "00" as output instead of current time. Once you stop and start again then the value is going to set.

Comment: This is because React state updates are not instantaneous, they are enqueued and processed asynchronously. The value you are logging right after `setCurrentTime(rightNowTime);` will be the value of `rightNowTime` from the current render cycle, not what it will be on a future render cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making things a bit more complicated than they need to be. I suggest storing only a start time and a current "tick" and compute the derived "state" of the minutes, seconds, and milliseconds between these two timestamps.

```
const App = () => {
  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState<number>(0);
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState<number>(0);

  // Store interval id in React ref
  const intervalRef = useRef<number | undefined>();

  const [disableStop, setDisableStop] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [disableReset, setDisableReset] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [disableStart, setDisableStart] = useState<boolean>(false);

  // Return cleanup function to clear any running intervals
  // on the event of component unmount
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }, []);

  const calculateTime = () => {
    setCurrentTime(Date.now());
  };

  const startTimer = () => {
    setDisableStart(true);
    setDisableStop(false);

    // Only update start time if reset to 0
    if (!startTime) {
      setStartTime(Date.now());
    }

    // Invoke once immediately
    calculateTime();

    // Instantiate interval
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      calculateTime();
    }, 1);
  };

  const stopTimer = () => { ... };

  const resetTimer = () => { ... };

  // Compute the minutes, seconds, and milliseconds from time delta
  const delta: number = currentTime - startTime; // in ms
  const minutes: string = Math.floor(delta / (1000 * 60)).toString();
  const seconds: string = (Math.floor(delta / 1000) % 60)
    .toString()
    .padStart(2, "0");
  const milliseconds: string = (delta % 1000).toString().padStart(3, "0");

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Stop Watch</h1>
      </div>
      <Layout seconds={seconds} minutes={minutes} milliseconds={milliseconds} />
      <Buttons ... />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit usestate-doesnt-work-first-time-when-given-date-in-string-while-implementing-st#70617216]

Comment: I think you should check if currentTime in start because it will reset if you start again if you stop the timer then start

Comment: @Jerson That's the current behavior in OP's code as well. ‍♂️ Figured they either wanted it like that, or they just haven't got that far yet.

Comment: @Jerson Thanks, added a check for the start time condition.

Comment: Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
useRef is giving above error. Any idea?

Comment: @rajm I'm not super familiar with Typescript, but I'm guessing it's complaining about the `<number | undefined>` type for the `intervalRef`. It doesn't appear to be an issue in the codesandbox. Have you tried `const intervalRef = useRef<Timer>();` or whatever type it's referring to?

Comment: Did not help :(

Comment: @rajm You may try `<any>` or removing the type altogether... either way though, this seems like an extracurricular issue to the question about the state. It would better to ask a new question with the specific code/typing you're now having an issue with. If anything you will get more eyes on it more quickly than discussing it here with me. Feel free to comment here with a link to it and I can also take a deeper look.

Comment: @rajm Has an answer here addressed/resolved your question/issue?

Comment: My query is resolved but Stop watch did not work since you not considered stopped time, I have updated code https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-lehmann-o4thw?file=/src/index.tsx @DrewReese

Comment: @rajm Ah, ok, I see what you mean. Seems to be working in your CSB, still have anything needs looked at?

Comment: I mean I made some changes to it. Now it's working. Same thing updated in CSB